# Knowing the caller of the rule in Makefile

Tags: makefile

Assume I have a complex Makefile with following snippet

```
test: abc
     ....
xyz: abc
     ....
abc: 
   #who called me?
```

Is there a way we can find who called abc?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to know? Is it for debugging or normal operation? Does the action of the `abc` rule differ depending on who called it? Can you modify the other rules to assist it this endeavor, or must `abc` figure it out alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No built-in way.  If you're using GNU make you could do it yourself using [target-specific variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html):

```
test: PARENT = test
test: abc

xyz: PARENT = xyz
xyz: abc

abc:
        @echo $(PARENT)
```